# Format table columns as percent, currency for pdf output (Rmarkdown)

Tags: r, datatables, knitr, kable

I have a Rmarkdown document in which I need to produce a table. The table has several columns, some of which are currency and some others are percentages. I need to produce a pdf output.

### Sample data

This will be enough:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(x = letters[1:3], y = c(10.20, 20.501, 30.3222), z = c(0.6, 0.065, 0.95))
```

### Alternatives I tried

I'm aware I can format each column for what I need, like this:

```
kable(df[, .(x, paste0("$", round(y, 0)), paste0(round(100 * z, 1), "%"))
```

Also, if I had html output *instead* of pdf, I could do something like

```
library(DT)
datatable(df) %>% formatCurrency(columns = 2, digits = 0) %>% formatPercentage(columns = 3, digits = 1)
```

### Difficulties I've had

I can't use the `DT::datatable` approach, as my output is pdf, and DT doesn't produce pdf / latex output.

I wouldn't like to use the `kable` approach, as it would be cumbersome to produce `paste0` code for each different case.

### What I'd like / want:

An option similar to the `DT` approach that produces pdf output.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Instead of writing `paste0` code, have a look at the `scales` package, with functions like `percent_format`, `dollar_format` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Axeman's advice, there are at least alternatives to use with `scales` and `formattable` packages:

```
# Option 1: scales
library(scales)
kable(df[, .(x, dollar(y, accuracy = 1), percent(z, accuracy = 0.1))])


# Option 2: formattable
detach("package:scales", unload = TRUE) #function percent has the same name
library(formattable)
kable(dt[, .(x, currency(y, digits = 0), percent(z, digits = 1))])
```